# keep getting the nullpointerException? i am trying to print out an image

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics

here is the main class

```
public class Testing extends JFrame{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Testing(){
    setContentPane(new Canvas());
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}
public static void main(String[] args0){
    new Testing();
}
```

}

and the error occurs in the Canvas class, the drawImage method. I've made a res folder where i put my images and use it as source folder.

```
public class Canvas extends JPanel{
Graphics g;
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
BufferedImage image;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public Canvas(){
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
    loadImage("/space.png");
    draw(g2);
}
public void draw(Graphics2D g2){
    g2.drawImage(image, 0,0,this);
}
public void loadImage(String path){
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(
            getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)
        );
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("image loading error");
    }

}
```

}

Thank you for the help.

and the error i got when i run the program.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Canvas.draw(Canvas.java:21)
at Canvas.<init>(Canvas.java:18)
at Testing.<init>(Testing.java:11)
at Testing.main(Testing.java:17)
```

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace to your original question.  Also please identify **the exact line of code** that produces the error.

Comment: no stacktrace is being printed out. the debug only says theres an nullpointerException to drawImage()

Comment: Look at `JNL`s answer or see this tutorial: http://zetcode.com/gfx/java2d/java2dimages/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- there isn't required to call something like as `PaintComponents(g);`, remove this code line, is useless
- painting in `Swing` is done in `paintComponent()` not `PaintComponents()` more in [`Oracle tutorial Working with Images`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html), search here for question tagged by  `paintComponent()`
- `JPanel` is `ImageObserver` then  `g.drawImage(image, 0,0,null);` should be  `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);`
- `new testing();` should be wrapped in `invokeLater`, more see in [`Oracle tutorial Initial Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)
- don't `setSize(800,600);` fro JFrame override `getPreferredSize` in `public class Canvas extends JPanel {`
- `public class testing extends JFrame{`

  1. should be `public class Testing {`
  2. create `JFrame` as local variable (similair as `BufferedImage image;`)

EDIT. something like as

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Image image = new ImageIcon("Images/mong.jpg").getImage();

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(800, 600);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }
};
```

Comment: not drawImage but paintComponent, no idea about an exception, post an stack trace,

Comment: @Bango: mKorbel's advise is the only one here so far that has any merit. You should follow it and ignore the others. 1+.

Answer (score 2):

where have you initialized Graphics2D object 'g' , you should properly initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

**[Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html)**

> protected Graphics2D() Constructs a new Graphics2D object.
>
> Since Graphics2D is an abstract class, and since it must be customized by
> subclasses for different output devices, Graphics2D objects cannot be
> created directly. Instead, Graphics2D objects must be obtained from
> another Graphics2D object, created by a Component, or obtained from
> images such as BufferedImage objects.

Use:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
g2.drawImage();
```